# Facebook Error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Hello i am using this code in android facebook app but getting this error.

```
             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
             params.putString("message", "Facebook Dialogs are easy!");  
             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(),null);
```

Thanks.

Comment: not familiar with the android sdk for facebook but it sounds like you need the user to grant the publish_stream permission

Answer (score 4):

Has the user actually given your app the `publish_stream` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)?

Check with a call to `/me/permissions`

Answer (score 1):

Facebook api was updated on 04 dec 2011.

For more information please refer [here](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/).